# how to install openvz on debian lenny 32 bit

Tags: installation, debian-lenny, openvz

I know there are plenty of tutorials for Etch, but I could not find any that is devoted to installing OpenVZ on Lenny. [There official guide](http://wiki.openvz.org/Installation_on_Debian) mixes Etch and Lenny and thus was unhelpful.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? What did you get?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial on howtoforge:
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-and-using-openvz-on-debian-lenny-amd64

The tutorial seems to be for x64 machines, but the author wrote enough comments for x86-machines into the article so you shouldn't have any problems.
I installed my host node using this howto and it works great.